# background-image animation not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-image, sprite

I am using the following script to animate a sprite for the background-image for a nav div:

```
$("li#test2").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).animate({
          'background-position-y': '-40'
        }, 500);
      },
      function () {
        $(this).animate({
          'background-position-y': '0'
        }, 500);
      }
    );
```

This works fine in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox.  You can see the page it is on [here](http://salliannputman.com/test.html).  Just hover over the first 'home' image in the nav bar.

Could someone let me know why it's not working in Firefox?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-position-x` and `background-position-y` are not standards.

If you want to animate, you must modify both values (x and y) with `background-position`.

look at these sites:

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like firefox supports `backgroundPositionY` property so you need to use the `backgroundPosition` property which expects both coordinates.

```
"backgroundPositionY" in document.createElement("div").style
//true for chrome, false for firefox


"backgroundPosition" in document.createElement("div").style
//true for both
```

Since jQuery won't support that out of the box, you need to use hook plugin like [this](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing a syntax error in slider.js on line 46. Maybe something wasn't closed properly?

Comment: Looking through the code, it looks like the last set of closing brackets is unnecessary. The `});` isn't closing anything.