# Firefox doesn't accept CSS class on element

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I have strange behaviour with firefox (other browser works good).

I have rule:

```
.feed.input.community .buttons .url {
    background-position-x: 9px;
}
```

After I call:

```
$('.input.feed').addClass("community");
```

You can see result on this screenshot.

[image]

Maybe anybody knows why or how I can determine why firefox not accept rule?

Comment: what is that strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your answer.  Read this post about the background-position support

[background-image animation not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466346/background-image-animation-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

This property is not a standard CSS3 property. Just a year ago, Firefox did not support this property. I have not found anything to show it does now.

See this: [Is background-position-x (background-position-y) a standard W3C CSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653685/is-background-position-x-background-position-y-a-standard-w3c-css-property)